# Taking the derivative of some function

Tags: integration, derivatives

Simple question about some function:

I define $$y =\exp\left(\int^x f(t)w(t) dt \right) $$ and i want to take the derivative with respect to x. Can I just say y'= $$f(x)w(x) \exp \left(\int^x f(t) w(t) dt\right) $$?

Consequently can I say that y'' = $$ \left( f'(x)w(x)+f(x)w'(x) \right) \exp\left(\int^x f(t) w(t) dt\right) +f(x)w(x)f(x)w(x)\exp\left(\int^x f(t) w(t) dt\right)= $$ $$\left( f'(x)w(x)+f(x)w'(x) \right) \exp\left(\int^x f(t) w(t) dt\right) +f(x)^2 w(x)^2 \exp\left(\int^x f(t) w(t) dt\right) $$

Generally, what is the difference between $$\int^x f(t)w(t)dt $$ and just $$\int f(x)w(x)dx $$

Comment: What are *aaaaaaalllll* the lower limits of the above integrals?!

Comment: Is it just notation ? I dont understand it completely. I assume its just the indefinite integral with respect to x?

Comment: perhaps it is "just notation", but it might be important, depending on the functions involved. Anyway, I think the lower limtis are lacking.

Comment: The book 'an introduction to ODE' written by Ravi P. Agarwal talks only about these kind of integrals.... So i don't think it's a lack of lower limits, it's just notation you and I dont understand :)

Comment: If your author means $$\int^xf(t)w(t)dt=\int_0^{x}f(t)w(t)dt$$ everything works out. (except for the second derivative, I think)

Comment: My mistake. Your second derivative is also correct! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition
$$x\mapsto y(x):=\exp\left(\int^x f(t)w(t) dt \right) $$
defines the function $y(\cdot)$ only up to a multiplicative constant $\ne0$. In fact, the right side has to be interpreted as follows: Assume that $t\mapsto F(t)$ is an arbitrary primitive of $t\mapsto f(t)w(t)$. Then $y(x):=\exp\bigl(F(x)\bigr)$. Two such primitives $F_1$ and $F_2$ differ by an additive constant $c\in{\mathbb R}$, therefore two candidates $x\mapsto y(x)$ satisfying your definition differ by a multiplicative constant $C:=e^c\ne 0$.

From $y(x)=\exp\bigl( F(x)\bigr)$ we get
$$y'(x)=\exp\bigl( F(x)\bigr)\cdot F'(x)=y(x)\cdot f(x)w(x)$$
and then
$$y''(x)=y(x)\bigl(f^2(x)w^2(x)+f'(x)w(x)+f(x)w'(x)\bigr)\ .$$
The "arbitrary multiplicative constant" is still present on the right side of the last equation, but the result is written in such a way that after this constant has been chosen once and for all no further ambiguity persists.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to $\int_{0}^{x}f(t)w(t)dt$ and $\int f(x)w(x)dx$? Well, if we differentiate the first and second, we arrive at $f(x)w(x)$, but for conceptually different reasons.

We know that $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{x}f(t)w(t)dt=f(x)w(x)$$

due to the following proof (part of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus):

Let $u(t)=f(t)w(t)$. Define $U(t)=\int u(t)dt$. From this, we have $$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{x}f(t)w(t)dt&=\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{x}u(t)dt\\
&=\frac{d}{dx}\left[ \int u(t)dt\right]^{x}_{0}\\
&=\frac{d}{dx}\left[U(x)-U(0)\right]\\
&=\frac{d}{dx}U(x)+\frac{d}{dx}U(0)\\
&=\frac{d}{dx}U(x)+0\\
&=u(x)\\
&=f(x)w(x).
\end{align}
$$

We know that $$\frac{d}{dx}\int f(x)w(x)dx=f(x)w(x)$$ on the basis of the fact that differentiation and integration are inverse operations just like addition and subtraction. They cancel one another, in other words.

### Attempt To Address Your Concerns More Aptly

Let's assume the author means $$y=\exp\left(\int_0^{x}f(t)w(t)dt\right).$$

Make the $u$ sub as above and say more aptly $$y=\exp\left(\int_0^{x}u(t)dt\right).$$

When we differentiate this, we must apply the chain rule: $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dv}\frac{dv}{dx}.$$

Let $v=\int_0^{x}u(t)dt$. We then have:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\exp(v)\frac{d}{dx}v\\
&=\exp\left({\int_0^x u(t)dt}\right)\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{x}u(t)dt\\
&=\exp\left({\int_0^x u(t)dt}\right)u(x)\\
&=\exp\left(\int_0^{x}f(t)w(t)dt\right)f(x)w(x).
\end{align}$$

### Second Derivative

$$
\begin{align}
y''&=\left[\exp\left({\int_0^x u(t)dt}\right)u(x) \right]'\\
&=\left(\exp\left({\int_0^x u(t)dt}\right)\right)'u(x)+\exp\left({\int_0^x u(t)dt}\right)u'(x) \quad (\text{product rule: } (fg)'=f'g+fg'.)\\
&=\exp\left(\int_0^{x}u(t)dt\right)u(x)u(x)+\exp\left({\int_0^x u(t)dt}\right)u'(x)\\
&=\exp\left(\int_0^{x}u(t)dt\right)u^2(x)+\exp\left({\int_0^x u(t)dt}\right)u'(x)\\
&=\exp\left(\int_0^{x}u(t)dt\right)u^2(x)+\exp\left({\int_0^x u(t)dt}\right)u'(x)\\
&=\exp\left(\int_0^{x}f(t)w(t)dt\right)f^2(x)w^2(t)+\exp\left({\int_0^x f(t)w(t)dt}\right)(f(t)w(t))'\\
&=\exp\left(\int_0^{x}f(t)w(t)dt\right)f^2(x)w^2(t)+\exp\left({\int_0^x f(t)w(t)dt}\right)(f(t)'w(t)+f(t)w'(t)).
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

When one writes
$$
\int g(x)dx,
$$
the usual meaning is **"an antiderivative of g"**.

When one writes 
$$
\int_a^bg(x)dx,
$$
one means the **"integral of g on $[a,b]$"** (or "definite integral"), which is a number defined using a limit of Riemann sums.

If one writes
$$
\int_a^xg(t)dt,
$$
then for each $x$ this gives some number (i.e., for each $x$ one gets a definite integral, that is a number) and so we have a function on $F(x)$. The **Fundamental Theorem of Calculus** states the fact that in this last case $F(x)$ is an antiderivative for $f(x)$.

Comment: and what does $$\int^x f(t) dt $$ mean? is it the same as F(X) ?

Comment: Probably. But it's a very unusual notation.

Answer (score 0):

If the functions $\,f,w\,$ are such that $\,f(t)w(t)\,$ has a primitive $\,F(t)\,$ in some interval containing $\,x\,$ , say in $\,[a,x]\,$ , then the FTC tells us that

$$\int_a^xf(t)w(t)\,dt=F(x)-F(a)$$  so

$$y=e^{\int_a^xf(t)w(t)\,dt=F(x)-F(a)}\Longrightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=y'=F'(x)\,e^{F(x)-F(a)}=f(x)w(x)\,e^{F(x)-F(a)}$$